# Add number into google map marker in android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose

I have a list of locations and I want to pin each location on the map and display the index number into each marker. how can I do this?
Note: I used jetpack compose

Comment: please post what you have done so far.

Comment: You can check out this link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/marker

Comment: I added a pic for each number and select different markers depending on the number.

Comment: @PedroRodriguez Indexes doesn't have specific numbers

Comment: You cannot currently do the number drawing part in Compose natively, but you can add your vote to this issue to make it possible: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/220892485